# given: $(x + 1) \frac{x}{2} = n$

Tags: calculus

Given: $(x + 1) \frac{x}{2} = n$

How to get $x$ 's expression by only n and numbers?

Thanks.
Sorry to ask this question here. As a programmer, I didnt do math for a long while. Need some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the following guide:

1. Multiply $x$ inside the braces.
2. Multiply $2$ on both sides.
3. Manipulate the equation such that it follows the form of $ax^2+bx+c=0$.
4. Use the formula $$x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: thanks. i recalled this now. LOL

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple quadratic: $$x^2+x-2n=0$$
using $$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{D}}{2a}$$
We get
$$x=\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+8n}}{2}$$